# if statement when environment variable exists/not exists in batch files

Tags: batch-file

I want to check if a certain environment variable is set in the PC. If yes do x if not do y.

I tried these and some variations of them:

```
IF EXISTS %SIGN% runtest.exe --redirect -l %NAME%
ELSE runtest.exe -l %NAME%

if "%SIGN%" == "" runtest.exe --redirect -l %NAME%
ELSE runtest.exe -l %NAME%
```

None of them work well in both cases (when the environment variable `SIGN` exists and when it doesn't exist). Sometimes just in one case...

Please can you help?
Thanks!

Comment: `if exists` checks for files. for variables do: `if defined sign` (without the percent-signs

Comment: @Stephan - make this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IF` [Conditionally perform a command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

```
IF DEFINED SIGN (
     runtest.exe --redirect -l %NAME% 
) ELSE (
     runtest.exe -l %NAME%
)
```

or shortly

```
IF DEFINED SIGN (runtest.exe --redirect -l %NAME%) ELSE (runtest.exe -l %NAME%)
```

Valid syntax:

- all `)`, `ELSE` and `(` must be on an only line as follows: `) ELSE (`

**Note**:

> `if DEFINED` will return true if the variable contains any value (even if the value is just a space).

According to above predicate, `IF DEFINED SIGN` condition seems to be equivalent to reformulated test `if NOT "%SIGN%"==""` but it is valid **in batch only**, where `%undefined_variable%` results to an empty string:

```
if NOT "%SIGN%"=="" (runtest.exe --redirect -l %NAME%) ELSE (runtest.exe -l %NAME%)
```

Otherwise, in pure CLI, `%undefined_variable%` results to `%undefined_variable%`

**Proof**:

```
==>type uv.bat
@echo undefined_variable="%undefined_variable%"

==>uv.bat
undefined_variable=""

==>echo undefined_variable="%undefined_variable%"
undefined_variable="%undefined_variable%"

==>
```

Answer (score 3):

`if exists` checks for files.

For variables do: `if defined sign` (without the percent-signs)